# Phonegap - Can hide div, but not show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

I've got a very simple PhoneGap project, with some messaging elements that get toggled on and off as required.  I'm using jQuery with this project, although the problem that I'm seeing occurs regardless of whether or not I use jQuery to show/hide the divs.

Anyways, the relevant markup goes like:

```
        <div class="event listening blink" id="waiting" >
            Waiting for Game
        </div>
        <div class="event listening blink" id="error" >
            Something bad happened...
        </div>
        <div id="running">
            <h1>Shake Me!</h1>
            <div id="deviceready">
                <p class="event listening" id="accelerometer">Waiting for accelerometer...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="complete">
            <h1 id="finalStatus">Game Over</h1>
            <div id="myRanking">
                <p class="event listening">You came in 100th place.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

...when the page loads, I hide all of these divs like:

```
$("#waiting").hide();
$("#running").hide();
$("#error").hide();
$("#complete").hide();
```

As various events happen in the app, I show the appropriate div, like:

```
$("#waiting").show();
```

Seems trivially simple, except the divs aren't reappearing.  Once a div has been hidden, it stays hidden for good.  There are no JavaScript errors being thrown, and the same thing happens even if I show/hide them the old-fashioned way using `document.getElementById("waiting").style.display = 'block';`.  I've got `console.log()` statements that confirm that `show()` is definitely being called.

So I'm at a loss as to how/why this is happening.  Has anyone encountered a similar problem in the past?  What was the solution?

Comment: have you tried to run ur app in the browser as well? did u encounter the same issue? also can you try to print the html in the div after the show, `alert($("waiting").html());`

Comment: I've had issues with the webview on phones where, if you've set a property like 'transform3d' that triggers hardware-acceleration, the visual rendering of the page doesn't match the DOM state. I don't know if thats what's happening here, but how i figured out if it was the problem was by actually logging the style object of the DOM element in question, to see if the object is actually visible, and then force a reflow/repaint somehow.

Comment: i have tried to use ur example above and seems to be working fine. unless the event that u r waiting for (to show the div) arrives before the div is actually hidden. can you some more of your code or the complete file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue (sort of).  Apparently jQuery was conflicting with some other script that was being used on the page.  I'm not sure which one, or what the conflict was, or how the conflict could have been so severe as to cause `element.style.display = 'block';` to stop working, but changing the order of the `<script>` tags in the HTML fixed the problem.